# Change parameters of a class when clicking button on different window

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm pretty new to c++ and Qt but I'm trying to create a simple battleship game. So far I have been able to set up the grid and also place ships but I wan't to put in a menu before the main game window where you choose "difficulty" which will determine how big the grid size for battleship is.

The code for drawing the game board goes as follows:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "boardrender.h"
#include "playerrender.h"
#include "../BattleScrabble/BattleshipBoard.h"
#include "../BattleScrabble/HumanPlayer.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
//    BattleshipBoard *a = new BattleshipBoard(10);
//    Ship *b = new Ship(AircraftCarrier);

    ui->battleshipBoardView->setMouseTracking(true);

//    BoardRender *scene=new BoardRender(a, ui->battleshipBoardView->width(), this);
//    ui->battleshipBoardView->setScene(scene);
    ui->battleshipBoardView->resize(ui->battleshipBoardView->width(),ui->battleshipBoardView->width());
    Player *b = new HumanPlayer(10,0);

    PlayerRender *a = new PlayerRender(b, ui->battleshipBoardView,this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

where `new HumanPlayer(10,0);` is the grid size.

And now the interesting part, the difficulty window:

```
#include "difficultywindow.h"
#include "ui_difficultywindow.h"
#include "DifficultyWindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
DifficultyWindow::DifficultyWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DifficultyWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

DifficultyWindow::~DifficultyWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void DifficultyWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    mWindow = new MainWindow(this);

    mWindow->show();
}
```

when I'm instantiating the "new MainWindow" is there a way to change the HumanPlayer parameters in this class instead?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

edit: and my main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "difficultywindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    DifficultyWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc In my main.cpp, should i post it too?

Comment: @eyllanesc So what would that look like? and how would I call that to my slot for the button press in difficultyWindow? Sorry for the long question, just a beginner :/

Comment: @eyllanesc so would something like  `mWindow(b)->show();` work?

Comment: the easiest thing is to make b public member of MainWindow class, for it in mainwindow.h: `public: HumanPlayer * b;` and in mainwindow.cpp change to `b = new HumanPlayer(10,0);`, then in the slot you could use: `mWindow->b->someFunction(some_attr);`

Comment: mWindow(b)? Before asking try it or at least think if the syntax is correct.

Comment: @eyllanesc true, the syntax wasn't good. I'm trying to make the `HumanPlayer *b` public in MainWindow.h but it gives the error `Expected a declaration`. Any idea where I'm going wrong? thank you for all your help btw

Comment: Share your code via github or drive, and I'll help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc okay thank you, ill pop a link in

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, just struggling to create a git. But I've done your changes and it looks like im making progress. the only problem i have is i dont quite understand what you mean by `someFunction(some_attr)`. Should the pointer be a human player or should it be a PlayerRender? the PlayerRender is what draws the board in Qt.

Comment: According to your question: *way to change the HumanPlayer parameter in this class instead*, I understand that you know how to change the attributes of HumanPlayer, that is, you must have a function that you have defined in the HumanPlayer class. If you can not upload it to github, upload it to any reliable media and share the link.

Comment: @eyllanesc Link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1ei7oc2ffjeqcy/BattleshipQuestion.zip?dl=0
difficultywindow.cpp is where the code for difficulty is, and mainwindow.cpp has the player render for creating the board

Comment: What parameter of HumanPlayer do you want to change?

Comment: @eyllanesc so i may have mis-framed the question - the first parameter of humanplayer is the size of the grid, so the HumanPlayer(10,0) means it will be a 10x10 board. but what I'd like to do is in difficultyWindow when the player clicks easy/medium/hard they will instead get a different sized grid based on their difficulty choice.

Comment: @eyllanesc if the code is poorly commented i apologize, i can answer any questions about it

Comment: See my answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make some modifications, to make your code more understandable you must first add a parameter to MainWidow, in this case it will be called grid

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(int grid, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Player *b;
    PlayerRender *g;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(int grid, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->battleshipBoardView->setMouseTracking(true);
    ui->battleshipBoardView->resize(ui->battleshipBoardView->width(),ui->battleshipBoardView->width());
    b = new HumanPlayer(grid, 0);
    g = new PlayerRender(b, ui->battleshipBoardView,this);
}
```

Then we will create an enumeration and to handle a signal instead of 3 we will use `QButtonGroup`:

**difficultyWindow.h**

```
class difficultyWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum Difficult{
       EASY,
        MEDIUM,
        HARD
    };
    explicit difficultyWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~difficultyWindow();

private slots:
    void onClicked(int id);
private:
    Ui::difficultyWindow *ui;
    MainWindow *mWindow;
    QButtonGroup *group;
};
```

**difficultyWindow.h**

```
difficultyWindow::difficultyWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::difficultyWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    group = new QButtonGroup(this);
    group->addButton(ui->easyDiffButton, EASY);
    group->addButton(ui->mediumDifficultyButton, MEDIUM);
    group->addButton(ui->hardDifficultyButton, HARD);

    connect(group, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)), this, SLOT(onClicked(int)));
}

difficultyWindow::~difficultyWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void difficultyWindow::onClicked(int id)
{
    int grid;
    switch (id) {
    case EASY:
        grid = 10;
        break;
    case MEDIUM:
        grid = 20;
        break;
    case HARD:
        grid = 30;
        break;
    }

    mWindow = new MainWindow(grid, this);
    mWindow->show();
}
```

**Note:** eliminate the slots, its are unnecessary for this case.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. One question though, what should I call my buttons to make sure that they're called by the case EASY etc? Right now with your code it builds without errors but when clicking the buttons nothing occurs. Thanks again!

Comment: I've tried it and it works fine, it removes all your generated files and recompiles it back.

Comment: Youre right, it works great now that i adjusted a little syntax mistake. Thank you!